# In R, plot emmeans of glmmTMB linear model. Error in linkinv(summ$the.emmean) : could not find function "linkinv"

Tags: r, plot, emmeans, glmmtmb

I would like to plot the emmeans of a glmmTMB model using plot().
When my glmmTMB model takes in log transformed data, plot(emmeans(glmmTMB_model)) works just fine.
However, when I attempt to plot the emmeans of the glmmTMB model of non-transformed data, I get the following error: Error in linkinv(summ$the.emmean) : could not find function "linkinv".

See my code below:

```
Site <- c(4,4,5,5)
Treatment <- c("Burnt_Intact-Vegetation","Burnt_Intact-Vegetation", "Burnt_Cleared", "Burnt_Cleared")
pH <- c(5.94, 5.91, 5.44, 5.49)

pH_EC_data <- data_frame(Site, Treatment, pH)

pH_model <- glmmTMB(pH~Treatment+(1|Site), data = pH_EC_data)
log10pH_model<- glmmTMB(log10(`pH`)~Treatment+(1|Site), data = pH_EC_data)


log10pH_analysis <- emmeans(log10pH_model, pairwise~Treatment, type = "response")
plot(log10pH_analysis)
##This plot works just fine.

pH_analysis <- emmeans(pH_model, pairwise~Treatment, type = "response")
plot(pH_analysis)
##This code results in the following error: Error in linkinv(summ$the.emmean) : could not find function "linkinv"
```

Note, log10pH_analysis and pH_analysis differ by one column.  Emmeans of glmmTMB of logged data creates a "response" column whereas the same manipulation of non-tranformed data resulted in an "emmeans" column.  See below:

**log10pH_analysis**

```
$emmeans
 Treatment               response     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 Burnt_Cleared               5.47 0.0167  2     5.40     5.54
 Burnt_Intact-Vegetation     5.90 0.0180  2     5.82     5.98

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log10 scale 

$contrasts
 contrast                                  estimate      SE df t.ratio p.value
 Burnt_Cleared - (Burnt_Intact-Vegetation)  -0.0329 0.00188  2 -17.520 0.0032 

Note: contrasts are still on the log10 scale
```

**pH_analysis**

```
$emmeans
 Treatment               emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 Burnt_Cleared             5.47 0.0176  2     5.39     5.55
 Burnt_Intact-Vegetation   5.90 0.0176  2     5.82     5.98

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                                  estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
 Burnt_Cleared - (Burnt_Intact-Vegetation)    -0.43 0.0249  2 -17.238 0.0033
```

Thank you.

Comment: Using the two-sided formula in emmeans() has it create a list of two emmGrid objects. I don't think that is what you want to llot, and I suggest removing the left-hand side (pairwise) and using just ~treatment

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if log10 is fully supported (I'll have to check). If you just use log() instead of log10, you'll get the same predictions after back-transforming to the response scale.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to duplicate this with a similar example. It is due to a coding error that I will correct in the next update of the package.

The problem is related to the fact that your `pH_analysis` object is actually a list of two `emmGrid` objects -- one for  the estimated marginals means, and the other for the pairwise comparisons of them. If you do

```
plot(pH_analysis, which = 1)    # or plot(pH_analysis[[1]])
```

it will work just fine. The error occurs in trying to plot the second one as well, and the coding error has to do with the fact that the pairwise comparisons are *not* on a transformed scale but it thinks they are.

I do suggest that you not use `plot()` on the results of an `emmeans()` call with a two-sided formula or list of specs; and instead pick out the part you actually want to plot. Also, I think you must have a fairly old version of **emmeans**, as the default for `plot()` in recent versions is `which = 1`.

Thanks for reporting this bug.

Comment: I originally created this code on version 3.6.3 and had no problems then moved to a new computer and downloaded R version 4.0.3 and that's when it began returning the error described above.  I guess I'm not sure what version of emmeans() I was running, but I assumed it was the most up to date with R v4.0.3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: At any rate, the interim solution is either to install emmeans from GitHub or to refit the model using log instead of log10. Either will yield the same estimates with type = "response"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that type = "response" causes the problem for the non-transformed data.

```
pH_analysis <- emmeans(pH_model, pairwise~Treatment)
plot(pH_analysis)
##Plots beautifully; problem resolved
```

Comment: That doesn't resolve the problem because it is desired to have the results on the response scale rather than on the log10 scale.